# Why is max_input_vars ignored?

Tags: php, forms

I have `max_input_vars` set to `10000` in `.htaccess`. `ini_get('max_input_vars')` correctly returns `10000` and `phpinfo` correctly shows the local value of `max_input_vars` to be 10,000 (with a master value of 1,000) and yet a sample script on a GoDaddy shared server with anything more than 1,000 `<input type="hidden" name="input[]" value="n">` fields only populates `$_POST['input']` with 1,001 elements, whereas when run on my local machine it works correctly. Both are running PHP 7.2 and both have `post_max_size 100M`.

Is there some server setting that means the local value of `max_input_vars` is ignored?

The script I'm using to test this is below. You enter the number of hidden input fields to create, click the "Create inputs" button, and then submit.

```
<pre>ini_get('max_input_vars'): <?php echo ini_get('max_input_vars'); ?></pre>
<form method="post">
  <div id="inputs"></div>
  <label for="number">Input vars:</label>
  <input id="number" type="number" min="0" max="2000" maxlength="4" step="1" value="">
  <button type="button" onclick="createInputs()">Create inputs</button>
  <pre>document.getElementsByClassName('input').length: <span id="count">0</span></pre>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<pre>$_POST: <?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>
<script>
function createInputs()
{

  var inputs = document.getElementById('inputs')

  inputs.innerHTML = ''

  var input
  
  for (var i = 1, n = document.getElementById('number').value; i <= n; ++i)
  {

    input = document.createElement('input')

    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    input.setAttribute('class', 'input')
    input.setAttribute('name', 'input[]')
    input.setAttribute('value', i)
    
    inputs.appendChild(input)

  }

  document.getElementById('count').innerText = document.getElementsByClassName('input').length

}
</script>
```

Before submitting form (on both local machine and remote server):

[image: Before submitting form]

After submitting form on local machine:

[image: After submitting form on local machine]

After submitting form on remote server:

[image: After submitting form on remote server]

Comment: What is your value for `post_max_size`?

Comment: 100M on both local and remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I was able to get it working by setting `max_input_vars=10000` in a `.user.ini` file in the document root. I suspect that cPanel was filtering the input before the rule in `.htaccess` was applied.